# iOS and UIKit class checking

Tags: ios, class, uikit

How do you programmatically check if `UIKit` has a given class?

For example, on iOS3 there's no `UINib`, but on iOS4 there is. I can build on SDK4, but if I try to run on an iOS3.0 device I'll meet an exception.

Comment: if ([object isKindOfClass:UIView.class]) - if you have existing objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [iOS 4 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-4_0/_index.html) state:

> iOS 4 includes a new UINib class to support rapidly unarchiving nib
>   files. While this class is new to iOS SDK 4, it was present but
>   private, in previous releases. Special care needs to be taken when
>   deploying code that uses the UINib class and also runs on iOS releases
>   prior to version 4. Specifically, you cannot determine the
>   availability of the class solely using the NSClassFromString function,
>   because that check returns a private class on iOS 3.x and earlier.
>   Instead, after getting the UINib class using NSClassFromString, you
>   must also use the respondsToSelector: method of the returned class to
>   see if it responds to the nibWithNibName:bundle: method. If it
>   responds to that method, you can use the class.